# Is there way to delete complete row from getView?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hi there I am facing issue when deleting row view from list. I just create a place order activity and there I register list and then create a class of cart Adapter.

When I delete the row it generates the exception can't delete the row. Is there any solution?

**PlaceOrder.java**

```
public class PlaceOrder extends Activity {

    String [] pIds; 
    String [] pNames; 
    String [] pPrizes; 
    static ListView lv;
    ImageView bck;
    String [] listImages;
    String food_id;
    String userdata[];
    Intent i;
    Intent intent;
    TextView totalprze;
    float tprize;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    TableRow p_order;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    List<String> cart=new ArrayList<String>();
    String [] pId;
    String [] PName;
    String [] pPrize;
    Intent intent_one;
    String userid;
    String status,message;
     String [] delete;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_order);

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
        bck=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder_bg_btn);
        totalprze =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_order_price);
        p_order=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.p_order);

        intent=new Intent(this,Food.class);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


        p_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {







                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Place Order</b>"+"<br>Do you want to continue ?"))

              .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        Cursor  cursor = new ShopingCartHelper(PlaceOrder.this).getData(userid);
                        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "View Cart",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            if (cursor .moveToFirst()) {

                                while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                                    String pid = cursor.getString(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex("id"));
                                    String pName = cursor.getString(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex("product_name"));
                                    String prize = cursor.getString(cursor
                                            .getColumnIndex("price"));

                                    cart.add(pid);
                                    cart.add(pName);
                                 //   System.out.print("Product Name "+pName+"Price"+prize+"id"+id+"\n");
                                    cart.add(prize);
                                    cursor.moveToNext();
                                }


                                int length=cart.size();
                                pId=new String[cart.size()/3];
                                PName=new String[cart.size()/3];
                                pPrize=new String[cart.size()/3];

                                //System.out.print(length+"\n\n\n\n Values of List \n\n\n\n");

                                int k=0;
                                String[] values=cart.toArray(new String[cart.size()]);

                            //   System.out.print("Values are :\n\n"+values);
                                int count=0;
                                for(int j=0;j<values.length/3;j++){
                                    pId[j]=values[count];
                                    count=count+1;
                                    PName[j]=values[count];
                                    count=count+1;
                                    pPrize[j]=values[count];
                                    count=count+1;

                                }

                                for(int i=0;i<pPrize.length;i++){
                                    System.out.println(pPrize[i]);
                                }
                            }      
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     new place_order().execute();


                 }
              })
              .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    );
              AlertDialog d = builder.create();
             // d.setTitle("Are you sure");
              d.show();

                TextView messageText = (TextView)d.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            }
        });

        i=new Intent(this,Menu.class);

        bck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

                    //bundle.putStringArray("images", ListImages);
                    bundle.putString("food_id", food_id);
                    bundle.putStringArray("images", listImages);
                    bundle.putStringArray("userData",userdata);
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        if(this.getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {

         Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();

         pIds=b.getStringArray("pId");
         pNames=b.getStringArray("PName");
         pPrizes=b.getStringArray("pPrize");
         userdata=b.getStringArray("userData");
         tprize=b.getFloat("totalprize");



         food_id=b.getString("food_id");
         listImages=b.getStringArray("images");
         String prz=Float.toString(tprize);
         totalprze.setText("$"+prz);

         delete=new String[pIds.length];
         for(int m=0;m<pIds.length;m++){
             delete[m]="Delete";
         }



         lv.setAdapter(new cartAdapter(PlaceOrder.this, pIds, pNames, pPrizes,userdata,delete));

         userid=userdata[0];

         pIds=null;
         pNames=null;
         pPrizes=null;
       }
    }
        public void onBackPressed() {
         pIds=null;
         pNames=null;
         pPrizes=null;
        }
}
```

**Cart Adapter.java**

```
public class cartAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{

     String [] pIdz;
     String [] pNamz;
     String [] pPrizs;
     String [] userData;
     String [] del;
    // List<String> imges;
     Context context;
     DrawerLayout dLayout;
    // private ShopingCartHelper obj;
     //ListView dList;

     private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
     JSONArray jCat = null;
     int count=0;
     ProgressDialog pDialog;


     public cartAdapter(PlaceOrder ctx,
         String[] pIds,String[] pNams, String[] pprise,String [] userdata, String[] delete) {
         pIdz=pIds;
         pNamz=pNams;

         context=ctx;
         pPrizs=pprise;
         userData=userdata;
         del=delete;

         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                         getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

     }

        @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(pIdz==null){
                Toast.makeText(context, "There is issue with net connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Intent i=new Intent(context,WelcomeActivity.class);
                //context.startActivity(i);
                return count ;
            }else{
                return pIdz.length;
            }


        }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;

    }

    public class holder{
         DrawerLayout dLayout;
         TextView pid;
         TextView pname;
         TextView pprise;
         Button delete;
         ListView lv;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       final  holder hldr=new holder();

          View rowView = null;
          rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_order_item_list, null);

          //hldr.dLayout= (DrawerLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_drawer_layout);
         // hldr.dLayout=(DrawerLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btndrawerLayout);
          hldr.pid=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_id);
          hldr.pname=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
          hldr.pprise=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
          hldr.delete=(Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete);   
          hldr.pid.setText(pIdz[position]);
          hldr.pname.setText(pNamz[position]);
          hldr.pprise.setText(pPrizs[position]);
          hldr.delete.setText(del[position]);

          hldr.delete.setTag(position);
           hldr.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int pid=Integer.parseInt(hldr.pid.getText().toString());
                new ShopingCartHelper(context).delProduct(pid);
                 pIdz[position]=null;
                 pNamz[position]=null;
                 pPrizs[position]=null;
                 del[position]=null;

                // new PlaceOrder().updateAdapter(context,pIdz,pNamz,pPrizs,del);
//              
             notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

          });

         return rowView;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


}
```

Comment: what are the logs you  are getting????

Comment: before i was geting exaption but now row can't delete but particular index of array is null so what should i do

Comment: the row is available but data is empty so i want data is null then don't create this row view

Comment: what do you see on the logcat? what exception?

Comment: For the love of god and all that is holy please format your code

Comment: Tip: use lists instead of arrays

Comment: not geting exception now just i click on the delete button i removed the data on particular index makes null so when notify method call the data will be delete but row remain empty so what should i do

Comment: You should format your code and remove all code that is not relevant to the issue so we can understand what is going on

Comment: @BabarAli please have a look at my solution , you have two choices to remove the row. if you want to use the same code then you have to delete the id from the array of string by traversing the whole array, so in order to reduce the effort you should use arraylist in place of array of strings. And do the same for other fields also

Answer (score 0):

As you want to remove the row from the list so you have to delete that explicitly for that you should declare Pidz like this

```
 ArrayList<String> Pidz;
```

And in your cartAdapter constructor

```
  Pidz = Arrays.asList(pIds);
```

Please modify your onclicklistener like this,

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

            int pid=Integer.parseInt(hldr.pid.getText().toString());
            new ShopingCartHelper(context).delProduct(pid);
             pIdz[position]=null;
             pNamz[position]=null;
             pPrizs[position]=null;
             del[position]=null;

             pIdz.remove(position);      
         notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

      });
```

Comment: let me chek i just follow systex let me check

Comment: sure , please follow this for other fields also wherever you are using array of strings in cartAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in CartAdapter.java, you have:

```
pIdz[position]=null;
pNamz[position]=null;
pPrizs[position]=null;
del[position]=null;
```

You don't delete the item in list, you only set it to 'null' value. So when call 'notifyDataSetChanged' you made a NullPointerException.

To fix this bug, change all String[] to ArrayList, and easy call Java.util.ArrayList.remove(index)

Comment: pIdz.remove(position); just got the unsuportedoperation exception here

Comment: Please change String[] to ArrayList<> for pIdz, pNamz, pRizs.

Comment: Still getting exception